# problem with trigger and on. event doesnt trigger the on method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to trigger the "modal:show" event from when .show-modal is clicked, but I get no respons when I trigger the event. I've tried many different implementations, but can't get it right.

```
$(".modal").on("modal:show", function (event) {
    onShowModal(event.id);
});

function onShowModal(modalId) {
    let $modal = $("#" + modalId);

    $modalBlack.fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $modal.fadeIn("fast", function () {
            $modal.trigger("modal:showing", { id: modalId });
        });
    });
}

$(".show-modal").click(function (event) {
    let modalId = $(this).data("modal-id");

    event.preventDefault();

    $(".modal").trigger("modal:show", { id: modalId });
});
```

Comment: `.trigger("modal:show", { id: modalId });` is not going to put the id on the event.  If you reference https://api.jquery.com/trigger you will see that the additional parameters will be extra arguments passed into the listener, in addition to the event

Comment: it doesn't fire with no extra parameters either

Comment: Seems to work for me, so I would assume it's some kind of syntax problem in your code but without more code to look at, I couldn't really say.

https://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/xpvt214o/1004860/

Answer (score 1):

To get your code working I had to make a few modifications. Try this:

```
<div class="modal">Generate my own HTML</div>
<div class="show-modal" data-modal-id="randomId">Make a button</div>
<div class="randomId" >Toggle, toggle.</div>
<script>
$(".modal").on("modal:show", function (event, idObj) {
    // The trick here is that the first parameter is the event.
    // The second parameter is the object that you send in on the 
    // triggering call. ($(".modal").trigger...)
    onShowModal(idObj);
});

function onShowModal(idObj) {
    let $modal = $("#" + idObj.id);
    // Don't forget to go into the object and get the Id.
    // I don't have modalBlack so my code broke at this point. 
    $modalBlack.fadeIn("slow", function () {
        $modal.fadeIn("fast", function () {
            $modal.trigger("modal:showing", { id: modalId });
            // modalId is probably going to be idObj.id.
        });
    });
}

$(".show-modal").click(function (event) {
    let modalId = $(this).data("modal-id");

    event.preventDefault();

    $(".modal").trigger("modal:show", { id: modalId });
     // Notice that you are sending this as an object {id:modalId}.
});
</script>
```